# proof of the minimal polynomial equation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to test my approach for a proof about minimal polynomial.  The proof is a construction based approach.

Let $\lambda_1, ... ,\lambda_d$ be distinct eigenvalues of $A$ ($n{\times} n$ symmetric matrix).

I need to show that $\prod_{i=1}^{d}(A-\lambda_i  I) v =0 \;\forall v \in \Bbb R^{n}$.

so let $Av =  \lambda v\:$  hold true where $v\in \Bbb R^{n}$ is an eigenvector of A.

Then the generalized equation can be written  $(A-\lambda I)v  = 0 $.

So since there are $d$ distinct eigenvalues,  I am not sure how to construct $\prod_{i}^{d}(A-\lambda_{i} I)v=0$.

so $v\neq 0 $ means that $d < n$ and a non-trivial solution must exist.

hence $\det(A-\lambda I)  = 0$,
which means the polynomial characteristic equation can be used.

$$p_{A}(A)= \prod_{i=1}^{d}(A-\lambda_{i} I) = \det(A- \lambda I)  = 0.$$

which has $d$ unique solutions for each distinct eigenvalue.

therefore $\prod_{i=1}^{d}(A-\lambda_{i} I) v=0$  (??)

Is thisa correct proof?  I will appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some problems with your approach:

- It's not clear what you mean by "construct $\prod_{i}^{d}(A-\lambda_{i} I)v=0$". An equation can be proven, but what could "constructing" an equation mean?
- *"so $v\neq 0 $ means that $d < n$ and a non-trivial solution must exist":* a non-trivial solution to **what** exactly? Also, keep in mind that the equation $\prod_{i}^{d}(A-\lambda_{i} I)v=0$ is supposed to hold for **all** vectors $v$.
- The characteristic polynomial is $p_A(\lambda)$; this is not equal to $p_A(A)$.  Also, I suspect that you are not meant to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem for this question (i.e. the statement that $p_A(A) = 0$).

---

A correct approach: first, show that $\prod_{i=1}^{d}(A-\lambda_{i} I)v=0$ happens whenever $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.  Then, using the fact that every $v$ can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors, conclude that this holds for **every** $v$.